# Why is remove_punct not removing apostrophes when tokenizing a corpus in quanteda?

Tags: r, text, quanteda

I am tokenizing a corpus of text but am having issues with removing punctuation. It seems as though most punctuation is being removed, but not apostrophes.

Code here:

```
all.tokens <-
  tokens(
    my.corpus,
    remove_punct = TRUE,
    remove_numbers = TRUE,
    remove_symbols = TRUE,
    remove_url = TRUE
  ) %>% tokens_tolower() %>% tokens_select(pattern = stopwords("en"), selection = "remove")
```

Anyone else have this issue? Any workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps because apostrophes are not punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

The [help document for `quanteda` package's `tokens()` function](https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens.html) explains that the function "`tokens()` is treated more as a constructor (from a named list) than a tokenizer. This allows users to use any other tokenizer that returns a named list, and to use this as an input to tokens(), with removal and splitting rules applied after this has been constructed (passed as arguments). These removal and splitting rules are conservative and will not remove or split anything, however, unless the user requests it."

This means that the default tokenizer (which is set by `word=` argument inside `tokens()` function) does not split contractions such as `can't`, `didn't`, `I'm`. This is intentional. Indeed, none of the standard tokenizer options to `what` argument in `tokens()` function has the ability to split contractions (Options are `“word”, “word1”, “word2”, “word3”, “word4”, “sentence”, “character”, “fasterword”, “fastestword”`). If you want to split these into separate words then you need to use a custom tokenizer to do so. Or you'd have to write your own function to split contractions and then apply tokens function.